# When using the tunnel riding feat, is the mount still required to make an Escape Artist check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, mount

Since most mounts do not even have an escape artist skill, I feel like this feat and a good portion of mounted combat in dungeons would be useless. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feat Tunnel Riding (*RS* 145) lets you and your mount ignore penalties AC and attack penalties for squeezing and to fight while squeezing.

Here's [squeezing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#terrainandObstacles):

> In some cases, you may have to squeeze into or through an area that isn’t as wide as the space you take up. You can squeeze through or into a space that is at least half as wide as your normal space. Each move into or through a narrow space counts as if it were 2 squares, and while squeezed in a narrow space you take a -4 penalty on attack rolls and a -4 penalty to AC.
>
> When a Large creature (which normally takes up four squares) squeezes into a space that’s one square wide, the creature’s miniature figure occupies two squares, centered on the line between the two squares. For a bigger creature, center the creature likewise in the area it squeezes into.
>
> A creature can squeeze past an opponent while moving but it can’t end its movement in an occupied square.

What the Tunnel Riding feat *doesn't* do is let you do is ignore the *next* part of squeezing:

> To squeeze through or into a space ***less than half*** your space’s width, you must use the Escape Artist skill. You can’t attack while using Escape Artist to squeeze through or into a narrow space, you take a -4 penalty to AC, and you lose any Dexterity bonus to AC.

Emphasis mine. So, yeah, riding an elephant through the kobold warrens is challenging, but riding a horse or other Large mount in a dungeon is slow and clumsy without the feat Tunnel Riding, and with the feat riding that Large mount around the dungeon becomes a fairly viable tactic--assuming, of course, that the DM's dungeons use standard 5 ft. squares.

**To Answer the Title**
Yes, a mount must still make an Escape Artist check to fit into very small spaces if the rider has the feat Tunnel Riding, but a Large creature traversing a hallway at least 5 ft. wide doesn't.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that "less than" part. Thanks for the clarification!